# confusion with helm "*-delete" hooks. Not delete previous resources when upgrade or install command

Tags: devops, kubernetes-helm

I am trying to implement a `"helm.sh/hook": crd-install` hook on `CustomResourceDefinition` object of course, of this way

```
apiVersion: apiextensions.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: CustomResourceDefinition
metadata:
  annotations:
    "helm.sh/hook": crd-install
    "helm.sh/hook-delete-policy": "before-hook-creation"
  name: certificates.certmanager.k8s.io
```

and when I am going to update or deploy a new instance with different name of my helm chart in the same cluster, I get this error

```
Error: customresourcedefinitions.apiextensions.k8s.io "certificates.certmanager.k8s.io" already exists
```

I suppose that  **`"before-hook-creation"`** delete policy specifies Tiller should delete the previous hook before the new hook is launched.

But I can't to make a deletion and re-creation of my different `CustomResourceDefinition` objects

I have my chart in a CI/CD process, and the idea is that when I execute a `helm upgrade` operation or even an  a new `helm install` operation with a new name of the chart in the same cluster, I don't have to force to delete the `CRDs` objects manually in order to it works

How can I get this purpose?

I have used  `"helm.sh/resource-policy": delete` and also the `"helm.sh/hook-delete-policy": "hook-succeeded"` and `"helm.sh/hook-delete-policy": "hook-failed"` hooks all together but I am confused in this point

I am using the following versions of helm

```
⟩ helm version
Client: &version.Version{SemVer:"v2.13.1", GitCommit:"618447cbf203d147601b4b9bd7f8c37a5d39fbb4", GitTreeState:"clean"}
Server: &version.Version{SemVer:"v2.13.1", GitCommit:"618447cbf203d147601b4b9bd7f8c37a5d39fbb4", GitTreeState:"clean"}
```

Like anecdote, I have the same YAML configuration in a secret resource, I mean I am creating that secret resource, but as a `pre-install` hook, but also using `"helm.sh/hook-delete-policy": "before-hook-creation"` and when I want to upgrade or install a new instance of my chart, it works.

I have made the same installing a `CRDs` as a pre-install hooks and it works

Why it works as a `pre-install` hook and not for `crd-install` hook?
Can I deploy CRDs kubernetes objects as a `pre-install` hooks? I mean it isn't a bad practice or it is recommendable?

Any support I will be highly grateful

**UPDATE**

Even having the CRDs object resources a a `pre-install` hook, if I delete the helm chart `helm delete --purge ...` and I create it again, I get the same error

```
Error: object is being deleted: customresourcedefinitions.apiextensions.k8s.io "certificates.certmanager.k8s.io" already exists
```

The previous hook resources are not being deleted in order to continue with the installation workflow without generate errors.

I mean, it process only works when I am going to make a helm install for first time and its post-correspondent upgrades operations

Comment: I am also facing this issue where the helm test failed due to the last test pods is still there. Have you got the solution for this?

Comment: @AmitKumar I just decided to install cert-manager CRDs in a separate `kubectl` command.

Comment: I figure it out that it is not related to helm-delete-hook-policy but other metadata like namespace and etc